# Flutter web Image loading in mobile view, but not in full view?

Tags: image, flutter, widget, flutter-web

I am using FadeInImage widget to load images from network

When the page is refreshed in mobile view from developers console, the images are loading fine, but in full view it gives me an Exception

```
The following ImageCodecException was thrown resolving an image codec:
Failed to load network image.
Image URL: https://api.gogoz.in/static/img/FF000001FV0000007.jpg
Trying to load an image from another domain? Find answers at:
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/web-images

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
...

Image provider: NetworkImage("https://api.gogoz.in/static/img/FF000001FV0000007.jpg", scale: 1)
Image key: NetworkImage("https://api.gogoz.in/static/img/FF000001FV0000007.jpg", scale: 1)
```

Answer (score 18):

**The issue:**

It seems that with the most recent Beta release 1.26 (Feb 2021), the default `renderer` seems to have switched from `html` to `canvaskit`.

**Fix:**

When working in `Web`, use the `html` renderer instead of the `canvaskit`. This is how:

- If you "run" from command line, use this:

`flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html`

- If you use Android Studio: Go to `Run/ Run.../ Edit Configurations.../`, then in `Additional arguments` add this `--web-renderer html`.